# Import Gridview to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I need to Import data from Grid view in asp.net to pdf file 
this is my Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvValues" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" PageSize="15" ItemType="Tayf.Models.Product" CssClass="table-striped table-condensed table table-bordered table-hover"
    OnRowDataBound="gvValues_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvValues_PageIndexChanging" meta:resourcekey="gvValuesResource1" EmptyDataText="No Products in your Pos">
        <EmptyDataRowStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="16pt" ForeColor="Red" />
           <RowStyle Wrap="true" />
               <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                       <ItemTemplate><%# gvValues.PageSize*gvValues.PageIndex+ Container.DisplayIndex+1  %></ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="Barcode" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Barcode" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Item Name" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource2" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:#.00}" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Price" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource3" />
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
                      <ItemTemplate><%# Item==null?"":  Item.PosInvoiceDetail == null || Item.PosInvoiceDetail.Count<1?"": "Invoice ID:" +  Item.PosInvoiceDetail.First().PosInvoiceMasterID.ToString()  %></ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

and this button

```
<asp:Button  ID="importData" runat="server" CssClass="btn-default" Text="Import To PDF" OnClick="importData_Click"></asp:Button>
```

and this is my Code

```
 protected void importData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
             "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gvValues.AllowPaging = false;
            gvValues.DataBind();
            gvValues.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End(); 
        }
```

But I have  an Error

which said

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Control 'MainContent_gvValues' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Don't think of it as exporting a grid view. Export the underlying data.

Comment: @mason Sorry , I edit it , I need to import data from gridview to pdf file

Comment: I know what you mean, but don't think about the gridview at all in the equation. Take the underlying data and use that to generate your PDF.

Comment: @mason please , Could you have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766985/an-exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception

Comment: for this you can easily use jquery plugin..

Comment: @NazirUllah , what is name of the JQuery plugin shall I use?

Comment: this error say that your gridview not inside the form tag , if are using master page must place your other page code inside form tag                "Additional information: Control 'MainContent_gvValues' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

Comment: try on the above , if not working then use the client script (jquery plugin) for that , but first you will convert your grid into HTML table from where you can import data on many type format

Answer (score 1):

- This exception occurs when one tries to export a GridView control to Word, Excel, PDF, CSV or any other formats. Here the .net compiler thinks that the control is not added to the form and is rendered

Solution of this Problem is  Just write below code in CS. File

```
   public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified AS.net
           server control at run time. */

    }
```