# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, io

I need to export data to pdf file ,
but I have `An exception of type

`System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`

this is my Code

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            GridView ExportGrid = new GridView();
            ExportGrid.AllowPaging = false;
            List<Tayf.Models.Product> DataLst = new List<Tayf.Models.Product>();

            DataLst = HttpContext.Current.Cache["productcache"] as List<Tayf.Models.Product>;

            ExportGrid.DataSource = DataLst;//DataSet1 has all values without paging
            ExportGrid.AllowPaging = false;

            ExportGrid.DataBind();

            ExportGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

my data is Very huge over than  1 million row and I need to export all data in one file

Comment: "was not handled". Use a try catch and print out the stack trace from the exception.

Comment: @MillieSmith will it solve the problem!?, it will just ignore the error

Comment: It will help you figure put what the problem is so you can fix it

Answer (score 0):

As your data is such big, maybe you should separate your data into many parts and write them into the pdf separately.

Comment: @Nesreenadly I'm not familiar with the tools you use in your code, but maybe you can write the file line by line? Sorry it's just my simple idea.